# open zeppelin contracts are missing in node_modules

Tags: solidity

I used npm install to install open zeppelin. the libray shows in node_modules but a lot of the contracts are missing. I've tried deleting it and reinstalling but I just keep getting errors about missing contracts.

```
Error: Could not find zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol from any sources; imported from /home/a/Documents/coin/contracts/token.sol
    at Resolver.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/resolver/dist/lib/resolver.js:53:1)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/resolver/dist/lib/resolver.js:5:42)
    at <anonymous>
Truffle v5.1.28 (core: 5.1.28)
Node v8.10.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Despite *ERC20Detailed* still being extant within OpenZeppelin's [online tutorial](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/erc20) it no longer exists when you download the package and take a peek inside.  I therefore ran into exactly the same problem you did.

This is due to a breaking change [introduced in OpenZeppelin Contracts 3.0](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/releases/tag/v3.0.0), namely:

> If you're using the ERC20 or ERC721 tokens however, you'll have to
>   remove all references to optional extensions (ERC20Detailed,
>   ERC721Enumerable, etc.) - these have been included in the base
>   contracts.

To get your code to work using version 3.0 you will have to use the standard ERC20 module.  For a very basic example of importing and using that:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyCoin is ERC20 {

  uint public initialSupply = 10000;

  constructor() public ERC20("MyCoin", "MC") {
      _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
  }
}
```